# Cannot find running sum of a blended chart in data studio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio, cumulative-sum, blend

I'm trying to create a chart for following big query using data studio. Instead, auto generating the chart from the GCP. I'm trying to create chart using tools in the data studio.

```
SELECT t.timestamp, sum(t.introduced_violation) 
OVER( 
PARTITION BY t.introduced_user_id 
ORDER BY t.timestamp desc 
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
as cumulative_introduced_violation, 
sum(t.fixed_violation) 
OVER( 
PARTITION BY t.introduced_user_id 
ORDER BY t.timestamp desc 
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
as cumulative_fixed_violation, 
FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE 
WHEN is_fixed = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS fixed_violation, 
SUM(1) AS introduced_violation, 
timestamp, introduced_user_id 
FROM `project_id.violation.table_name` 
where introduced_user_id = 'username@company.com' 
and timestamp >=1622556834000 
and timestamp <=1631231999999 
group by timestamp, introduced_user_id 
order by timestamp desc) as t;
```

[Expected output from the query:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46x6z.png)

At first, I try to create chart for the inner query (below). I succeed this step by creating 2 charts and blending them together.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
WHEN is_fixed = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS fixed_violation, 
SUM(1) AS introduced_violation, 
timestamp, introduced_user_id 
FROM `project_id.violation.table_name` 
where introduced_user_id = 'username@company.com' 
and timestamp >=1622556834000 
and timestamp <=1631231999999 
group by timestamp, introduced_user_id 
order by timestamp desc;
```

[Expected output from inner query:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A7KP.png)

As in the query output for introduced_violation and fixed_violation values are RunningSUM values.

Is there is a way to find the RunningSUM of introduced_violation and fixed_violation columns in the blended charts or some other way to do the whole scenario?

Comment: Hello, can we adjust your query to a public bigquery dataset like `bigquery-public-data`. if not can you provide the schema of your table and some sample rows? that will help a lot to understand your question.

Comment: Hello there, I'm unable to upload the schema here but in the description I have uploaded screenshots.

Comment: You don't have to upload you production schema but a mockup of it to understand your data table structure.  If you are using data studio you can add a metric value and then use *running calculations* to apply *running sum* to your column.

Comment: In addition, you can put your custom query as a datasource.